# How to use ActionSheet in ST2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to use an actionsheet but am unclear where to place it. I have tried adding it to a button event function but it doesn't show (the modal screen does however). I get a message about ActionSheet#show showing a component that currently doesn't have any container. Please use Ext.Viewport.add() to add this component to the viewport. Not sure how to do that - using Ext.Viewport.add() doesn't work for me - i may be because of my layout which is:

I have a viewport controller/view which is a card layout. When I click a button I have a function in the viewport controller that loads a new controller/view card in the viewport.   The actionsheet is in one of these cards. The app is to big to post so hopefully it makes sense.

I have tried adding the actionsheet in my view items array but do not know how to make it show - making a reference to the xtype actionsheet doesn't return an object with a show() method it seems.

Edit: after more experiments it seems the issue is that I am placing it inside of a card - the card layout container has a relative position and the actionsheet absolute - somehow this is causing the actionsheet to go off screen. Setting card container to absolute fixes it but now I have problems with navbar positions. Suggestions?

So a bit stuck...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do to show your action sheet :

```
var actionSheet = Ext.create('Ext.ActionSheet', {
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Delete draft',
            ui  : 'decline'
        },
        {
            text: 'Save draft'
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            ui  : 'confirm'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.Viewport.add(actionSheet);
actionSheet.show();
```

Comment: And how do you get the button that was selected?